# How to break text from one line to another line in my list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created this shopping list app and it is working fine. Only issue that I am facing now is breaking a long string to next line. I am using word-wrap but it is not working.

So When I enter a very long word `(Helooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo)` etc. I want it to break the word and show it in next line like

> (Helooooooooooooooo
>   oooooooooooooooooooo)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <input id="add" type="text" placeholder="Type new item here"
            autocomplete="off" autofocus/>
    <ul id="item_list">
        <li id="base" class="hidden">
            <input class="check" type="checkbox"> <span class="item">Item</span>
            <button class="delete_item hidden"></button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item {
  font-size: 15px;
  /* width: 50%; */
  color: #000;
  margin: 8px 0 0 20px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Please check full and working code at this JS Fiddle  - http://jsfiddle.net/varunksaini/Zjxq5/10/

Comment: textbox cannot able to break the text.. you should you textarea for that

Comment: `<input>` cannot do that.

Comment: I don't want to break the input in text box, I want to break it when it got displayed in my list below input box. If you use my fiddle and enter a long string you will see that it keep going and part of string is not displayed and overlapped by my delete button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the problem is in the `.item` element and not the `input` field.

You need to modify your CSS as follows:

```
#item_list li {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  xxoverflow: hidden;
  xxwhite-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 50px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  xxword-wrap: break-word;
}

.check {  /* DO NOT float .item... */
  float: left;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.item {
  font-size: 15px;
  /* width: 50%; */
  color: #000;
  margin: 8px 50px 0 20px; /* add right margin to allow for delete button */
  word-break: break-all;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/hpa87/

Results look like:

[image]

In `#item_list li`, remove the rules for `overflow`, `white-space` and `word-wrap`, these are not needed.

Do not float `.item`.

For `.item`, set `display: inline-block` (`block` also works), set `word-break: break-all` to take care of long words, and set `text-align: left` (overrides an earlier CSS rule causing text to be aligned center).

**Note:** If you don't want your delete button to float over any of the description text, add either some right padding to `.item` or some right margin.

Comment: Thanks, That's what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id="add" type="text" placeholder="Type new item here" autocomplete="off" ></textarea>

#add{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to break the input in text box, I want to break it when it got displayed in my list below input box. If you use my fiddle and enter a long string you will see that it keep going and part of string is not displayed and overlapped by my delete button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some textarea to achieve this requirement. By default make the height of textarea look like text box

You can use this plugin http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

Comment: I don't want to break the input in text box, I want to break it when it got displayed in my list below input box. If you use my fiddle and enter a long string you will see that it keep going and part of string is not displayed and overlapped by my delete button.